# Faster way to load another page without using iframe

Tags: web-applications, iframe

I have a main page with a form and an iframe which show result of a form. Every time user changes something in the form, the page in the iframe is re-loaded to show the result. However,iframe is really slow. Is there a faster way to perform same action like iframe? or is there a way to make iframe faster? Thank in advance.

Edit: iframe is not refreshed after every key presses. For example, if user choose "apple" in the form, the form is submitted to php which then retrieve apple photo and then shown it in iframe. My problem is loading is really slow.

Comment: It seems like you are not really communicating using server so why not just use Javascript to do it.

Answer (score 0):

whether you just refresh the iFrame or get data via ajax, there will still need to be an http request, I guess your options are to look at optimising the data returned and how this is rendered and looking to see if the number of calls can be reduced, ie if the iframe is being refreshed after every key press, maybe detect when the user stops typing, then refresh the iframe?